# Finding a primitive element in a field with 27 elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to construct a field with 27 elements, and find a primitive element in that field. I considered the irreducible polynomial $f(x)=x^3+2x+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. Then I considered 
$$\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle f\rangle.$$
This is a field with $3^{\deg f}=3^3=27$ elements. I know that the unique elements of this field are given by 
$$\{a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2:a_i\in\mathbb{Z}_3\}$$
where $t=x+\langle f\rangle$. Now my question is, what is an efficient way (for beginners) to find a primitive element of this field? One could argue that it suffices to find an element $u\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle f\rangle$ with $\text{ord}(u)\neq 1,2,13$, but finding such a $u$ is computationally tedious (at least to me). Any comments or advice appreciated.

Comment: The field is described differently in the duplicate target (the constant term changes sign), but the effects of this are easy to accommodate for.

Comment: Anyway, $t^3=t-1$ so by the Frobenius we have $t^9=t^3-1=(t-1)-1=t+1$. Consequently
$$t^{13}=t\cdot t^3\cdot t^9=t(t-1)(t+1)=t^3-t=-1.$$ This implies that $t$ has order $26$.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because I already did so in the other thread. I firmly believe that high rep users should not recycle their own answers to such an extent unless they can add something else to the answer (the situation in the question may call for such additions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$1$ has order $1$ and $2$ has order $2$. Any other (non-zero) element has order $13$ or $26$. Take an arbitrary element, like $t$, and calculate $t^{13}$ (for instance by repeated squaring: find $t^3$, then square that twice to get $t^{12}$, then multiply by $t$; this is much faster than multiplying $t$ by itself $13$ times).

If it turns out that $t^{13}=2=-1$, then you're done. If $t^{13}=1$, then $-t=2t$ has order $26$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How did you see that "any other (non-zero) element has order 13 or 26" (of course I am assuming you didn't check this for all 27 elements one by one).

Comment: @ilovebulbasaur It's a cyclic group with $26$ elements. Such a group necessarily has one unit, and one element of order $2$, and the rest have order $13$ or $26$. Alternately, if an element has order $2$, then that means it is a root of the quadratic polynomial $x^2-1$. But the only roots to that polynomial are $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Squaring is rather inefficient this time when the equation is tailor-made for using the Frobenius and gives $t^{13}=-1$ rather easily. See my comment under main. Also, I think it is questionable that a high-rep user recycles ideas from their own old posts.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It's a _lot_ easier than searching, especially on mobile, and in particular when I don't remember exactly whether I have, indeed, answered such a question before. Yes, I know it's not the ideal response, but I like it better than answering in a comment.

Comment: To agree with Arthur, I don't see where the harm is in repeating a similar answer, especially when it is clear that he thought about the question instead of merely copying and pasting an old answer.

Comment: @ilovebulbasaur We have a rule about duplicate questions. And high rep users should be role models rather than try and harvest as many upvotes as possible. Arthur isn't the worst, but those people have spent a lot of time on the site, and should know better, and search for similar questions rather than rush to answer. I am more lenient about new users for A) they haven't been around long enough, and B) actually need a bit more rep to participate in all the site functions. The latter stops being a factor at 25000 pts, but out of inertia the transition need not be immediate.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Fair enough. I respect your view on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

From Arthurs answer we know that just guessing an element $at^2+bt+c$, it will likely be primitive. We have to choose at least one of $a$ and $b$ non-zero, so trying $t$ itself first is a good start. I wanted to add how the computation reduces to taking powers of matrices, i.e., linear algebra.

Identifying a polynomial $at^2+bt+c\in\mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle f\rangle$ with the vector $(a,b,c)^T\in\mathbb Z_3^3$, the multiplicative action of $t$ is given by the matrix
$$
Z = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is obtained from $t(at^2+bt+c) = bt^2 + (a+c)t + 2a$.

Obviously $Z^2\neq I$, since $t^2\neq 1$ and using your favorite method of computing powers of matrices you get $Z^{13} = 2I \neq I$ as well. Hence $t$ is a primitive element in $\mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle f\rangle$.

If this didn't work out, you could now try other matrices $aZ^2+bZ+cI$ and compute their powers.